# Write to Word Document from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to write to Word Document from a VBA macro, but I am having trouble with syntax to generate headers, paragraphs, tables etc...

This example writes two lines to a Word Document, but both come out as header style. I would like one line header and one line in paragraph or "normal" style...

```
   Dim wdApp As Word.Application
   Set wdApp = New Word.Application

   With wdApp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Documents.Add

    With .Selection        
        .Style = "Heading 1"
        .TypeText ("My Heading")
        .TypeParagraph

        .Style = "Normal"
        .TypeText ("Some regular paragraph text")

    End With
```

Comment: Record your steps in Word macro recorder and read the code Word makes.

Comment: Don't see any issues with your code.. It works fine for me

Comment: it works, but everything is styled as heading-1.

Comment: I've `Heading 1` style for first row and  `Normal` style for second: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TvFZL.png

Comment: simco - true, I simplified example and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I want.

```
With .Selection
    .Style = "Heading 1"
    .TypeText "Header 1"
    .TypeParagraph

    .Style = "Heading 2"
    .TypeText "Header 1.1"
    .TypeParagraph

    .Style = "No Spacing"
    .TypeText "some text"
    .TypeParagraph

    .Style = "Heading 1"
    .TypeText "Header 2"
    .TypeParagraph
End With
```