# VBA Excel replace Word text with Excel cell value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Good morning,

I would like to replace the address in Word using the one, placed in the Excel cell.

My situation looks like in the image below:

[image]

I have got an address in Excel and I want to paste in in the Word bracket, based inside the table cell.

There are some solutions:

[Write to Word Document from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173560/write-to-word-document-from-excel-vba)

[Pasting a String from excel to Word using word-VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855613/pasting-a-string-from-excel-to-word-using-word-vba)

[VBA from Word to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159890/vba-from-word-to-excel)

[VBA macros: Excel to Word text replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817263/vba-macros-excel-to-word-text-replacement)

which differs from my situation.

My code so far looks like this:

```
 Sub RamsOpen()
 Dim appWD As Word.Application
 Set appWD = New Word.Application
 Dim docWD As Word.Document
 Set docWD = appWD.Documents.Open(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\RAMS.docx.docm")
 appWD.Visible = True

 Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D18").Copy

 docWD.Content.InsertAfter Range("A1")

 End Sub
```

The Word document is opening, but I don't know, where my text has been copied.

The god hint appears to be here:

https://exceloffthegrid.com/controlling-word-from-excel-using-vba/

but applies to the blank Word document I think.

Comment: Where does `range("A1")` refer to on your word doc?

Comment: I don't know. I was guessing, that to my table as shown in the pic above.

Comment: I did a few things with Excel and Word together a while back, if I remember correctly, the way to reference the table cells is using the [`Table.Cell` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.cell). I'll leave that there for you but will see if I can dig my project up.

Comment: That would be fantastic. I tried several time to achieve my goal. On top of that this is not only one place, where I want to input the data.

Comment: It seems I hadn't sent that application home unfortunately, only one that is Word only and I asked questions about data from word to excel.

Comment: If you can't work out the cell referencing (or if it's too cumbersome), you might consider inserting a bookmark at the destination and writing your value to the document bookmark (I inserted a bunch of UserForm values to a word doc this way with relative ease).

Comment: [Here is a good writeup on Word Bookmarks from wordmvp](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/WorkWithBookmarks.htm)

Comment: Of course, if the Excel cell's content is variable and you want the Word document to automatically update any time the Excel value is changed, it can all be done via OLE linking with no VBA code at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I know of inserting data to a Word document is by using the `Bookmarks` object ([Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.bookmarks)) ([wordmvp writeup here](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/WorkWithBookmarks.htm) - very easy to follow).

Taking that into account, as you are controlling this from Excel, I'd put your address value into a `String` variable and assign that variable to a bookmark on the document.

Something like:

```
Dim appWD As Word.Application
Set appWD = New Word.Application
Dim docWD As Word.Document
Set docWD = appWD.Documents.Open(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\RAMS.docx.docm")
appWD.Visible = True
Dim ExcelAddressValue as String

ExcelAddressValue = Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D18").Value

docWd.Bookmarks("YourBookmarkNameHere").Range.Text = ExcelAddressValue
```

Comment: If you didn't read it, the wordmvp article leads on to another one about writing to bookmarks without deleting them - definately worth a read if you will be over writing the same document (but not so relevant if you are using a template document each time and saving as a different doc or not saving changes)